# Ruby 2.7.4 & 3.0.0 fails on macOS Big Sur (11.2.3): undeclared identifier RSA_SSLV23_PADDING

Tags: ruby, openssl

Trying to install Ruby 2.7.4 & Ruby 3 on Intel Mac 11.2.3 and I'm seeing the following error during compilation (installing using `ruby-install` (https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). I'm seeing the following error:

```
                                                   ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING'
    DefRSAConst(SSLV23_PADDING);
    ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:58: note: expanded from macro 'DefRSAConst'
#define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
                                                         ^
<scratch space>:144:1: note: expanded from here
RSA_SSLV23_PADDING
^
107 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkey_rsa.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
!!! Compiling ruby 2.7.4 failed!
```

Also, FYI:

```
❯ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

Comment: You need to install OpenSSL via homebrew, or whatever package manager you use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just for future reference, if someone is facing something similar with `rvm` just uninstall `openssl@3` using brew and instead install `openssl@1.1`

Comment: This answer was a life-saver. For more context, if anyone is running into issues and seeing make log lines that look like this when trying to install a ruby via `rvm` then this is likely your solution.

`Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /User/xxx/.rvm/log/1677787143_ruby-xxx/make.log`

And then in that log file:
`make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2`

Comment: This worked in M2 pro (macOS: 13.4.1-arm64)

Comment: This worked for my error `Error running '__rvm_make -j8'`. It's perfect solution.

Comment: same, 1. `brew uninstall openssl@3`, 2. `brew install openssl@1.1` 3. install rvm 4. `brew install openssl@3`

Answer (score 14):

If you already are using `rvm` to install ruby versions and have `openssl@3` installed, you can fix it by running the following:

```bash
rvm install 3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
```

If you don't have `openssl@3` installed yet, you can install it with:

```bash
$ brew install openssl@3
```

I found this solution in [this Github issue](https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/issues/9#issuecomment-1683015411)

Answer (score 4):

`ruby-install` takes care of installing the OpenSSL dependency for you, but there was a bug in `ruby-install` where it wasn't specifying the exact `openssl` version that needed to be installed. Thankfully that's been fixed:

1. Upgrade `ruby-install` to >=0.8.3 (e.g., `brew upgrade ruby-install`) which pins the openssl dependency for ruby at 1.1
2. Install ruby 3 (e.g., `ruby-install ruby 3.0.2`)

Details:

This was solved in `ruby-install` (first reported with https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/409). Homebrew defaulted `openssl` to 3.0 (the latest major version) but Ruby hasn't yet added support for OpenSSL3.0. As such `openssl` dependency `ruby-install` was attempting to use was the wrong version (Ruby is still on 1.1).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution that worked was:

1. **Install openssl v1.1 with brew:**

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

2. **Install the new Ruby version pointing to the openssl v1.1 directory:**

```
rvm install ruby-3.2.3 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```

Comment: brilliant !!! 